# How to get dragged column in datagridview when AllowUserToOrderColumns = true

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, drag-and-drop, datagridviewcolumn

I have a windows form application in which i have a datagridview with AllowUserToOrderColumns = true, then user change column order via drag and drop.

How can i know which column is dragged ?

Answer (score 0):

When you set **AllowUserToOrderColumns = true** then you will know the column name in **ColumnDisplayIndexChanged**

```
Private Sub Datagridview1_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnEventArgs) Handles dgvGuru.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged

     MsgBox(e.Column.Name)

End Sub
```