# Datagridview Cancel Drag and Drop on Filler Column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, drag-and-drop

I have a datagridview with the AllowUserToOrderColumns property set to true.

I also have a column at the end of the grid which has AutoSizeMode set to fill, this serves to fill the grid so that rows look "complete"

How would I mark this column to disable reordering on this column only?

I have tried something like the following

```
Private Sub dgvAdjustments_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewColumnEventArgs) Handles dgvAdjustments.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged
    If e.Column Is TheFillerColumn Then
        e.Column.DisplayIndex = theGrid.Columns.Count - 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Which this post [How to get dragged column in datagridview when AllowUserToOrderColumns = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022205/how-to-get-dragged-column-in-datagridview-when-allowusertoordercolumns-true)
sort of suggested

However trying to do what I want to do in this event throws an error as you can't set the display index on a column that is being adjusted.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SynchronisationContext`'s `Post` method.

In C#, you will have for example :

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(delegate(object o)
    {
        if (Column1.DisplayIndex != 1)
            Column1.DisplayIndex = 1;
    }, null);
}
```

Also, don't do `e.Column.DisplayIndex = ...` but `TheFillerColumn.DisplayIndex = ...` instead, as the moved column can be another one and be moved after `TheFillerColumn`.

Comment: A few modifications and the behaviour is more as I would expect. Its ashame the dragging outline still appears but im sure that once the user has tried a few times and it just reverts back to the original position they will get the idea. (They probably wouldn't even drag it anyway, just precautionary)